# ASP.NET Core: HttpContext.SignInAsync doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core

I've implemeneted asp.net core authorization:

Login controller action source code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<LoginViewResponse> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var response = new LoginViewResponse { IsAuthorized = false, RedirectPageUrl = "dashboard" };
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return response;

            var user = new User { Login = viewModel.Username, Password = viewModel.Password };
            var result = await _userService.CheckUserExist(user);

            if (!result)
                return response;

            var userDetails = await _userService.GetAsync(user.Login, user.Password);

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userDetails.Login),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userDetails.Login),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1),
                IsPersistent = true
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                    authProperties);

            response.IsAuthorized = true;
            return response;
    }
```

Configure source code

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseFileServer();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
            var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict
            };
            app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);
        }
```

ConfigureServices source code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                    {
                        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
                        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                    });
    }
```

Dashboard page source code:

```
[Authorize]
public class DashboardModel : PageModel
{
   public void OnGet()
   {
   }
}
```

I send ajax request to the Login action and execute HttpContext.SignInAsync(***) method.

But I don't have access to the dashboard page, 'cause redirect push me back to the login page.

Any idea why this happened? Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean `ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)` in your `AuthenticationProperties`.

Comment: Thank you Xerillio, but It doesnt's help.

Comment: Can you show the full contents of `Configure`? I think you also have to `UseAuthentication` **before** `UseAuthorization`.

Comment: Thank you so much!
You are right, I have to use UseAuthentication before UseAuthorization